# Birt error on Redhat when using charts

Tags: linux, redhat, birt

I get error when trying to render Birt reports containing charts on a redhat server.
It works fine when reports don't contain any chart.
It works fine when report are generated on windows.

Birt version : 4.4.2
Redhat version : 7.2
Tomcat version : 8.0.39
Java version : openjdk version 1.8.0_91
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

I tried all available formats for the chart : SVG, BMP, JPG and PNG. I get a different class in error when I use SVG but same kind of error.

The main error is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.image.JavaxImageIOWriter
```

Here is the complet error stack :

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.throwDummyException(ReportEngineService.java:1115)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:943)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runAndRenderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunAndRenderActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunAndRenderActionHandler.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.RunFragment.doService(RunFragment.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.FramesetFragment.service(FramesetFragment.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet.__doGet(ViewerServlet.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doGet(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:160)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2396)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:937)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.image.JavaxImageIOWriter
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.eclipse.EclipseConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(EclipseConfigurationElement.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.util.PluginSettings.getPluginXmlObject(PluginSettings.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.util.PluginSettings.getDevice(PluginSettings.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.api.ChartEngine.getRenderer(ChartEngine.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.prepareDeviceRenderer(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.generateRenderObject(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:972)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.processExtendedContent(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localizeForeign(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localize(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.traverse(HTMLAbstractLM.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.traverse(HTMLAbstractLM.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.handleVisibility(HTMLAbstractLM.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLRowLM.handleVisibility(HTMLRowLM.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.layoutChildren(HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:181)
    ... 37 more

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:srvrhel7bkp.ao.local
    {}:org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.throwDummyException(ReportEngineService.java:1115)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:943)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runAndRenderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunAndRenderActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunAndRenderActionHandler.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.RunFragment.doService(RunFragment.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.FramesetFragment.service(FramesetFragment.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet.__doGet(ViewerServlet.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doGet(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:160)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2396)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:937)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.image.JavaxImageIOWriter
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.eclipse.EclipseConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(EclipseConfigurationElement.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.util.PluginSettings.getPluginXmlObject(PluginSettings.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.util.PluginSettings.getDevice(PluginSettings.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.api.ChartEngine.getRenderer(ChartEngine.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.prepareDeviceRenderer(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.generateRenderObject(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:972)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.processExtendedContent(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localizeForeign(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localize(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.traverse(HTMLAbstractLM.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.traverse(HTMLAbstractLM.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.handleVisibility(HTMLAbstractLM.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLRowLM.handleVisibility(HTMLRowLM.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.layoutChildren(HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:181)
    ... 37 more


org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.utility.BirtUtility.makeAxisFault(BirtUtility.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.RunFragment.doService(RunFragment.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.FramesetFragment.service(FramesetFragment.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet.__doGet(ViewerServlet.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doGet(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:160)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.throwDummyException(ReportEngineService.java:1115)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:943)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runAndRenderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunAndRenderActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunAndRenderActionHandler.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2396)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:937)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.image.JavaxImageIOWriter
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.eclipse.EclipseConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(EclipseConfigurationElement.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.util.PluginSettings.getPluginXmlObject(PluginSettings.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.util.PluginSettings.getDevice(PluginSettings.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.api.ChartEngine.getRenderer(ChartEngine.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.prepareDeviceRenderer(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.generateRenderObject(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:972)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationBase.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationBase.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.birt.chart.reportitem.ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.onRowSets(ChartReportItemPresentationProxy.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.processExtendedContent(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localizeForeign(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.LocalizedContentVisitor.localize(LocalizedContentVisitor.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.traverse(HTMLAbstractLM.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.traverse(HTMLAbstractLM.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.handleVisibility(HTMLAbstractLM.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLRowLM.handleVisibility(HTMLRowLM.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.layoutChildren(HTMLRepeatHeaderLM.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:181)
    ... 37 more
```